# Custom class producing ClassNotFoundException on itself

Tags: java

It feels like I'm not understanding some kind of fundamental Java principle, but for some reason I can't deserialize my class within itself. When I run this in the main class, the compiler catches a `ClassNotFoundException`. Here is my class:

```
public class DataMaps<T> extends HashMap<String, T>{
private T t;

public void serialize() {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("stopMap.ser");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(this);
        oos.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public HashMap getMap() {
    //De-serialize map stored in memory
    HashMap map = null;
    try
    {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("stopMap.ser");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        map = (HashMap)ois.readObject(); //CLASSNOTFOUNDEXCEPTION
        ois.close();
        fis.close();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return map;
}
```

}

```
public class Main {

private Stops stop;
private DataMaps<Stops> stopsDataMap;
private String[] stopInfo;

public Main() {
    stopsDataMap = new DataMaps<Stops>();
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("stops.txt"));
        String line = br.readLine();

        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            stopInfo = line.split(",");
            stop = new Stops(stopInfo[0], stopInfo[2], stopInfo[4], stopInfo[5]);
            stopsDataMap.put(stop.getStopId(), new Stops(stopInfo[2], stopInfo[4], stopInfo[5]));
            System.out.println(stop);
        }
        //stopsDataMap.serialize(); //commented out since the file exists

        System.out.println(stopsDataMap.getMap().toString()); //Produces the error

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("Hello");
    new Main();
}
```

}

At first I had my serialized map cast to my created class `DataMaps` and `DataMaps<T>` but those did not work, so I went and tried to convert the serialized data to the `HashMap` my class extended and still get the error. I don't know what's going on, if someone could point out theissue here?

Here is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DataMaps
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:623)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1610)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1515)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1769)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
at net.mastrgamr.gtfs.static_objects.DataMaps.getMap(DataMaps.java:40)
at net.mastrgamr.gtfs.Main.<init>(Main.java:33)
at net.mastrgamr.gtfs.Main.main(Main.java:43)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Comment: I compiled your code (changing a Stop to a String), and it works :/ stopsDataMap.put("A","B");
        stopsDataMap.serialize();
        System.out.println(stopsDataMap.getMap().toString()); result > Hello
{A=B}

Comment: I'm not sure what happened, but I uncommented the "serialize()" code and re-ran the program. and it works fine.
I guess my old serialized file produced a corrupt file?

Comment: see my answer, you recreated the file and corrected the package name :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I can see the problem from the stack trace. The serialisation is happening at

```
net.mastrgamr.gtfs.static_objects.DataMaps.getMap
```

But the exception is

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DataMaps
```

If this were the same DataMaps class it would read

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.mastrgamr.gtfs.static_objects.DataMaps
```

You have serialised the data to the file but then added a package to DataMaps, which makes them effectively different classes.

Comment: OHHH, I'm so stupid! It took me a while to figure it out, but I guess I screwed myself by serializing the data then rearranging files in my project. Wow...